# Unique column validator in Spring

Tags: java, spring, unique, validation

I want to add validator which will return error if value is not unique. How to do this? This is my current validator:

```
@Component
public class AddFormValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return AddForm.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        AddForm addForm = (AddForm) target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "title",
                "title.empty", "Title must not be empty.");
        String title = addForm.getTitle();
        if ((title.length()) > 30) {
            errors.rejectValue("title", "title.tooLong",
                    "Title must not more than 16 characters.");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "content",
                "content.empty", "Content must not be empty.");
        String content = addForm.getContent();
        if ((content.length()) > 10000) {
            errors.rejectValue("content", "content.tooLong",
                    "Content must not more than 10K characters.");
        }

    }
```

I want to validate title.

Comment: _if value is not unique_ Value of what? Unique with regards to what?

Comment: Title column must unique from News table. There must be no news with equal titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are doing your database access, you should probably inject a repository that query the database to check if the title already exist. Something like :

```
@Component
public class AddFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    NewsRepository newsRepository;       

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return AddForm.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        AddForm addForm = (AddForm) target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "title",
                "title.empty", "Title must not be empty.");
        String title = addForm.getTitle();
        if ((title.length()) > 30) {
            errors.rejectValue("title", "title.tooLong",
                    "Title must not more than 16 characters.");
        }

        New new = newsRepository.findByTitle(title);
        // New already exist
        if (new != null) {
            errors.rejectValue("title", "title.alreadyExist",
                    "New title already exist");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "content",
                "content.empty", "Content must not be empty.");
        String content = addForm.getContent();
        if ((content.length()) > 10000) {
            errors.rejectValue("content", "content.tooLong",
                    "Content must not more than 10K characters.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Because the check and whatever repository action you then do with the validated object will (possibly) not have been done in the same transaction. The title might exist right after you check for it.

Comment: That was an example in the simplest form. He  certainly must add something to be able to handle concurrency

Comment: But how? I do not know

Comment: It depend on your use case... I don't know what you are doing with the object after it has been validated. Are you using JPA?